# Something wrong with SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, primary-key, syntax-error

Having a bit of trouble with this guys, im sure its pretty obvious to someone who knows it but im getting a syntax error on this statement

```
    sql = "ALTER TABLE " & TableName & " ADD COLUMN Prk COUNTER PRIMARY KEY(" & X & ")"
    Dim PrimarySet As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    PrimarySet.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

A bit of background info ive successfully connected to a database using OLEDB and it would seem that I cant save the table without entering a primary key. Im using this statement to enter a primary key that would have a AutoNumber column. The plan being that when i create new rows and columns that the autonumber would go along with it and create a list of numbers. If i've got the wrong end of the stick and this wont't work please let me know, been trying to get my program working for like two days straight

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What are the details of the exception?

Comment: Umm whats RDBMS? Sorry im a newbie at this, and ill get the exceptions up in a second

Comment: @Mohjo what Database server ie SQLServer MySql etc.

Comment: @Mohjo Just a note, if you see a new term, such as RDBMS, you'd be better first doing a quick web search. We're here to help, but a quick search over common terms will: 1) get you more info than what we can share in comments, 2) show you've done research into your issue, and 3) perhaps, in some cases, help re-phrase your question in such a way to promote better/quicker answers.

Comment: Ill keep that in mind, sorry, it does seem a bit lazy just asking doesnt it? Im using Microsoft Access and the deatils are **OleDbException was unhandled Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be MS Access. If so then you don't need the bracket stuff at the end of the query. Something like this should work:-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN Prk COUNTER PRIMARY KEY
```